# Manipulate list of themes in wp-admin

Tags: multisite, themes, wp-admin

I'm running a multisite network with 100+ themes installed and activated. Is there a way to manipulate the list of available themes in wp-admin so that certain themes appear in the list first? (a kind of "Featured" or "recommended") After the first 9 or so alphabetical as default would be fine.

Obviously Googling the words "wordpress" and "themes" has been pretty fruitless in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came up with a silly but effective measure to get certain themes at the front of the list. Because themes are listed alphabetically, it was possible to manipulate the output by changing the theme name, specifically by adding a symbol to the front of the theme name it will appear at the start of the list.

I settled for a non-breaking-space `&nbsp;` as it didn't effect the name visually. You could also try invisible ascii characters. HTML is stripped so don't bother trying that.

```
/*
Theme Name: &nbsp;Ribbon
Description: A customisable theme
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably not without editing core files. I haven't found any hook you could use.

If you look in the file `wp-admin/themes.php` and follow the program flow until the list of themes will be displayed, you can find the class `WP_Themes_List_Table` in `wp-admin/includes/class-wp-themes-list-table.php`.

This class generates the HTML list. Following the `prepare_items()` method, WordPress get the list of available themes from the function `get_themes()` which doesn't have a hook either.

What you can do is limit the result to allow only certain themes with the filter `allowed_themes` called in the function `get_allowed_themes()`.

Comment: Yeah this seems to be the case. Thanks for researching it though.

Comment: I worked it out! See my answer