# Hide a theme on list of themes in wp-admin without editing core files

Tags: multisite, themes, wp-admin

I'm running a multisite network with 200+ themes installed and activated. Is there a way to manipulate the list of available themes in wp-admin so that **certain theme does not appear in the list**? I want to do it without editing core files.

I know WordPress gets the list of available themes from the function `get_themes()`. And that there is a function called `get_allowed_themes()` that might be the solution. But no idea about how to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following filter works in **Multisite** in the following screens:

- `/wp-admin/network/themes.php`
- `/wp-admin/network/site-themes.php?id=1` (individual sites allowed themes)

```
add_filter( 'all_themes', 'wpse_55081_remove_themes_ms' );
function wpse_55081_remove_themes_ms($themes)
{
    unset($themes['Twenty Ten'], $themes['Twenty Eleven']);
    return $themes;
}
```

---

For the regular theme selector in a **single site** or **sub-site of a network** `/wp-admin/themes.php` (Appearance -> Themes), looks like there's no hook...

- [Manipulate list of themes in wp-admin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/29485/12615)
- [Reordering themes in admin panel](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/36220/12615)

I found that `$wp_themes` global var holds the array with all themes, but couldn't manage to unset items in it...

The old jQuery trickery does the job, but pagination may become *funny*...

```
add_action( 'admin_head-themes.php', 'wpse_55081_remove_themes' );

function wpse_55081_remove_themes()
{
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
        $('div.available-theme:contains("comicpress")').remove();
        $('div.available-theme:contains("twentyten")').remove();
        $('div.available-theme:contains("starkers")').remove();
    });     
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

---

#### Update

Looks like there's a new hook on the block: `extra_theme_headers`.
But there's something weird:

- it is [documented](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/extra_theme_headers) as a new filter in WP 3.4
- but it appears in `wp-includes/deprecated.php` (?!)

```
/*
 * The returning $arr is always empty, but we are able to unset items in the global $wp_themes
 * Works in all theme screens, Multisite or Single Site (and doesn't bugs pagination)
 * 
 * It is defined this way: apply_filters( 'extra_theme_headers', array() )
 * The array value is always empty but, if we return it, the filter doesn't works..
 *
 */
add_filter( 'extra_theme_headers', 'wpse_55081_remove_themes_everywhere', 10, 1 );

function wpse_55081_remove_themes_everywhere($arr)
{
    global $wp_themes;
    unset($wp_themes['Convertible/Convertible'], $wp_themes['grido-child'], $wp_themes['ilost'], $wp_themes['parallels'], $wp_themes['twentyeleven']);
    // return $arr;
}
```

Comment: The second looks better than the first one, since it uses `$themes` as a global var. I'm going to try out it. Thanks.

Comment: The second code works only for the admin page devoted to manage themes, not for the theme editor select menu.

Comment: @grosshat : I've updated my answer with an explicit differentiation of where each code applies.

Comment: @grosshat : please check the last update. Only one filter can handle everything, but there's something I don't get about it (see code comments).

Comment: Yep, I see. Weird, documented as a new filter and at the same time already deprecated. I'll try out it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
add_filter( 'wp_prepare_themes_for_js', 'hideThemes');
function hideThemes($arr){
    foreach($arr as $key => &$value){
        //unset what you want
    }
    return $arr;
}`
```

Or alternatively:

```
add_filter( 'wp_prepare_themes_for_js', 'hideThemes');
function hideThemes($arr){

    unset($arr["twentyfourteen"]);
    unset($arr["twentythirteen"]);
    unset($arr["twentytwelve"]);

    return $arr;
}`
```

Comment: Please explain _why_ this answer is helpful.

Comment: This is helpful because it is the answer - I actually prefer this method to the accepted solution - as this doesn't rely on and functions/methods in deprecated - I modified the code slightly which makes even simpler (added to the answer above)

Answer (score 0):

Copy and past in **functions.php**

```
add_filter( 'wp_prepare_themes_for_js', 'hideThemes');
function hideThemes($arr){

    unset($arr["twentyfourteen"]); 
    unset($arr["twentythirteen"]);
    unset($arr["theme-folder-name"]);

    return $arr;
}
```